# convert a String into a bidimensional list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have the following string:

```
890000071100000006000207000002060400000972000006080300000501000200000004650000089
```

and I would like to transform it into a bi-dimensional list so that it looks like this:

```
[[8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6], [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 2, 0, 6, 0, 4, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 9, 7, 2, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4], [6, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9]]
```

Does anyone know how to do this in Python?

This is what I did:

```
board_str = "890000071100000006000207000002060400000972000006080300000501000200000004650000089"

def convert(boardpm: str) -> list:
    list = []

    for i in range(0, len(boardpm)):
        list.append(boardpm[i])

    boardpm = [list[i:i+9] for i in range(0, len(list), 9)]

    return boardpm
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please share a bit more about the problem? it's hard to understand what isn't working for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! it is already solved, I just needed to add the data type to fill it with integers. I needed to use this afterwards in another function in order to solve a sudoku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[list(board_str[i:i+9]) for i in range(0, len(board_str), 9)]
```

> ```
> [['8', '9', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '7', '1'],
>  ['1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '6'],
>  ['0', '0', '0', '2', '0', '7', '0', '0', '0'],
>  ['0', '0', '2', '0', '6', '0', '4', '0', '0'],
>  ['0', '0', '0', '9', '7', '2', '0', '0', '0'],
>  ['0', '0', '6', '0', '8', '0', '3', '0', '0'],
>  ['0', '0', '0', '5', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0'],
>  ['2', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '4'],
>  ['6', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '8', '9']]
> ```

or - if you wanted integers instead of strings - use

```
[list(map(int, board_str[i:i+9])) for i in range(0, len(board_str), 9)]
```

> ```
>  [[8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 1],
>   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6],
>   [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0],
>   [0, 0, 2, 0, 6, 0, 4, 0, 0],
>   [0, 0, 0, 9, 7, 2, 0, 0, 0],
>   [0, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0],
>   [0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
>   [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],
>   [6, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 9]]
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! that is helpful, I actually needed to transform the data type into integer.

Comment: I added it into my answer.